# Replace image with text after 5 seconds delay

Tags: jquery, image, html, text, replace

**Goal**

Replace one div with another after 5 seconds delay using jQuery.

**Description**

I would like to show an image in a div for 5 seconds and after that it should be replaced with text in another div.

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="outer">Image here</div>
<div id="text">Text here</div>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("div#outer").fadeOut("slow", function ()
            {
                $("div#outer").remove();
            });
         }, 5000);
     });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Demo Link : http://jsfiddle.net/pHJgP/8/

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="outer"><img src="http://existdissolve.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/microsoft-logo-64x64.png" alt="" /></div>
<div id="text" style="display:none">Text here</div>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            $("div#outer").fadeOut("slow", function ()
            {
                $("div#outer img").remove();                
                $("div#outer").html($("div#text").text());
                $("div#outer").show();
            });
         }, 5000);
     });
```

hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: can we loop through settimeout

Comment: otherwise it will do the fadeout only once

Comment: hmm, yes you can use loop for that.

Comment: This was helpful, I needed to hide the text first and then once the image is gone then the text should be displayed. This was something I forgot to mention in the description but you were one step ahead of me :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $("div#outer").fadeOut("slow", function ()
                {
                    $("div#outer").hide();
                    $("div#text").show();
                });
             }, 5000);
         });
    </script>
```

Or if you're actually trying to move the text contained in `div text` into `div outer`, do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    $("div#outer").fadeOut("slow", function ()
                    {
                        $("div#outer").html($("div#text").html()); //.html or .text
                    });
                 }, 5000);
             });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is getting the text to only show after the image is gone - then here is an option that saves you having to do any JavaScript work with the text container.

Simply position the image container over the text, and fade out as you already are, like so:

---

​**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        var $el = $('div#outer');        
        $el.fadeOut("slow", $el.remove);
     }, 5000);
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="transition-wrapper">
    <div id="outer">Image here</div>
    <div id="text">Text here</div>
</div>
```

​
**CSS**

*Note that colours here are just for illustration*

```
.transition-wrapper {
    position: relative;    
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
#outer {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
}
#text {
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/mJUzr/